# PHP Include from second domain/subdomain on same server

Tags: php, url, curl, include

I try to include a php file from the same server but a different domain within a php site (domain.com).

```
include 'domain2.com/file.php';
```

the file should look like this for example:

```
echo 'test';
```

I now want the main site to have the file.php included to echo 'test' on the site.
However, it doesn't.
Does anybody have an idea how I could solve that?

My thoughts are the following, though I cannot solve it myself. Maybe they help you to come up with a solution:

- It seems like it is included but the file.php does not return anything, because the php is being run on 'the other domain's server'. So the echo could be done in the other file, but is not included within the main site.

Note that if I include via path, it works:

```
include '../domain2/file.php';
```

Note also that `allow_url_include` and `allow_url_fopen` are allowed in the php.ini.

Comment: _"Note that if I include via path, it works"_ - note that you already did that with your first version - `domain2.com/file.php` is also a "path." Unless you _actually_ meant, that you used `http://domain2.com/file.php` in the first version?

Comment: _"the file should look like this for example"_ - that would not even be valid PHP code, you'd need to wrap that into `<?php ... ?>` first of all.

Comment: The basics are simple: An include via the file system gets you the file's _content_, an include via a URL gets you the script's _output_.